# повторяется вывод из sql базы в dataGridView C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, datagridview

Каждый раз,при нажатии на кнопку обновить,выводятся данные из моей таблицы товаров повторно,даже те,которые уже существуют.Подскажите,как сделать условие,что бы при нажатии,выводилось только свежие добавленные товары.
https://pp.userapi.com/c639731/v639731252/5912a/0KBVvA91S5Q.jpg

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    m_dbConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbFileName + ";Version=3;");
    m_dbConn.Open();
    m_sqlCmd.Connection = m_dbConn;

    string query = "SELECT * FROM tovari";

    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, m_dbConn);

    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        data.Add(new string[5]);

        data[data.Count - 1][0] = reader[0].ToString();
        data[data.Count - 1][1] = reader[1].ToString();
        data[data.Count - 1][2] = reader[2].ToString();
        data[data.Count - 1][3] = reader[3].ToString();
        data[data.Count - 1][4] = reader[4].ToString();

    }

    reader.Close();

    m_dbConn.Close();

    foreach (string[] s in data)
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы каждый раз добавляете строки, но не удаляете старые, попробуйте так:

```
// Очищаем строки
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

// перед добавлением новых
foreach (string[] s in data)
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s);
```

Comment: Спасибо,все работает!